# Recommend best constructor with attribute?

Tags: c#, constructor

Is there a way to denote the best constructor to use in C#, so that a developer knows which to pick by default?

Say you have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId, DateTime mySpecialDate, DateTime myOtherDate, bool isProduction)
        : this(controlNumber1, controlNumber1, companyNumber, recordId, mySpecialDate, myOtherDate)
    {
        IsProduction = isProduction;
    }

    public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId, DateTime mySpecialDate, DateTime myOtherDate)
        : this(requestReferenceId, controlNumber1, companyNumber, recordId)
    {
        MySpecialDate = mySpecialDate;
        MyOtherDate = myOtherDate;
    }

    public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId, DateTime mySpecialDate)
        : this(requestReferenceId, controlNumber1, companyNumber, recordId)
    {
        MySpecialDate = mySpecialDate;
        MyOtherDate = mySpecialDate;
    }

    public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId)
        : this()
    {
        if (controlNumber1 == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Parameter: cannot be 0", "controlNumber1");
        if (recordId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Parameter: cannot be 0", "recordId");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyNumber))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Parameter: cannot be empty", "companyNumber");

        RequestReferenceId = requestReferenceId == 0 ? 1 : requestReferenceId;
        ControlNumber1 = controlNumber1;
        ControlNumber2 = controlNumber1;
        RecordId = recordId;
        CompanyNumber = companyNumber;

    }
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyStringProperty = string.Empty;
        MySpecialDate = DateTime.Now;
        MyOtherDate = MySpecialDate;
        RequestReferenceId = 1;
        ControlNumber1 = 1;
        ControlNumber2 = 1;
        TransactionNumber = 1;
        ReferenceNumber = 1;
        IsProduction = true;
    }

    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
    public DateTime MySpecialDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyOtherDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsProduction { get; set; }
    public int RequestReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int ControlNumber1 { get; set; }
    public int ControlNumber2 { get; set; }
    public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    public int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecordId { get; set; }

    public string TraceNumber
    {
        get {  return string.Format("{0}-{1}", ControlNumber2, RecordId)}
    }

}
```

And want to inform the developer that the version below is the recommended one to use:

```
public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId, DateTime mySpecialDate)
```

is there something in C# like below to do this? I know you can make up an attribute in-house, but is there a C# feature to do this? Am I missing something basic..oops... C#?

```
[Recommended]
public MyClass(int requestReferenceId, int controlNumber1, string companyNumber, int recordId, DateTime mySpecialDate)
```

Comment: you could use /// comments so they can see your note in the intellisense

Comment: Highlight it with a comment in XML documentation, e.g. `/// <summary>Recommended ctor<summary>`

Comment: So...be brave...add an answer!

Comment: What makes one constructor "better" than another - I think XML documentation than explains when _each_ constructor should be used would be helpful.

Comment: If one constructor is better than the others than why foresee the others in the first place ? In a good design every constructor has its place. It is really up to the user of the classes to see which one best fits his needs.

Comment: You could also consider using optional arguments and having fewer constructors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: You could use the `ObsoleteAttribute`, but that might lead to confusion if its not actually obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'd advise you to chain your constructors the *other* way round - make the ones with fewer parameters chain (possibly indirectly) to a single constructor with *all* the parameters, and make that the only one which sets anything. That saves your assignments being scattered all over the place as they are at the moment

Secondly, I'd consider using optional parameters instead of all that overloading:

```
public MyClass(
    int requestReferenceId,
    int controlNumber1,
    string companyNumber,
    int recordId,
    DateTime mySpecialDate, = default(DateTime)
    DateTime myOtherDate = default(DateTime),
    bool isProduction = false)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you only have a single constructor, so you don't have to "recommend" anything. Developers have to specify arguments for all the required parameters, but can choose which of the optional parameters they specify arguments for. Don't forget that different developers may be in different contexts - if you've recommended the overload without the `isProduction` parameter but they *want* to specify the `isProduction` parameter, that causes a conflict between your advice and what they need to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `[Recommended]` attribute because

1. You don't know the usecase of the developer so you can't tell which is most appropriate.
2. I would hope that you don't leave knowingly-bad implementations in your code so this situation isn't anticipated.

Depending on the exact situation you have a few options:

#### XML comments

By using XML comments, it will be picked up by Intellisense and shown to the developer when using your construct. Visual Studio has a shortcut for this by typing `///` which expands it to

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

#### [Obsolete]

Instead of marking one overload as a higher priority, you could mark the others as a lower one. This is done by using the `[Obsolete]` attribute, indicating usage of that method is strongly discouraged.

---

I would ask myself the question why this situation occurs though. Why are your overloads not equivalent? It seems like there is a core issue that needs to be addressed.

Consider using optional parameters to reduce the overload mess that is your code right now.

Comment: Take note that [optional parameters have their own issues with regards to versioning](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/08/10/versioning-issues-with-optional-arguments.aspx), which is something to consider if you're writing a library.